# How to solve "RuntimeError: 'len' is not supported in symbolic tracing by default" for vision transformers?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to create a feature extractor using `from torchvision.models.feature_extraction import create_feature_extractor`.

The model I am trying to use is from the vit_pytorch (link: https://github.com/lucidrains/vit-pytorch). The problem I face is that when I create a model from this lib:

```
from vit_pytorch import ViT
from torchvision.models.feature_extraction import create_feature_extractor


model = ViT(image_size=28,
        patch_size=7,
        num_classes=10,
        dim=16,
        depth=6,
        heads=16,
        mlp_dim=256,
        dropout=0.1,
        emb_dropout=0.1,
        channels=1)

random_layer_name = 'transformer.layers.1.1.fn.net.4'

feature_extractor = create_feature_extractor(model,
                                             return_nodes=random_layer_name)
```

and when trying to use the `create_feature_extractor()` on this model I always get this error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 2
      1 # torch.fx.wrap('len')
----> 2 feature_extractor = create_feature_extractor(model,
      3                                              return_nodes=['transformer.layers.1.1.fn.net.4'])

File ~/Mokslas/AI/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/models/feature_extraction.py:485, in create_feature_extractor(model, return_nodes, train_return_nodes, eval_return_nodes, tracer_kwargs, suppress_diff_warning)
    483 # Instantiate our NodePathTracer and use that to trace the model
    484 tracer = NodePathTracer(**tracer_kwargs)
--> 485 graph = tracer.trace(model)
    487 name = model.__class__.__name__ if isinstance(model, nn.Module) else model.__name__
    488 graph_module = fx.GraphModule(tracer.root, graph, name)

File ~/Mokslas/AI/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/fx/_symbolic_trace.py:756, in Tracer.trace(self, root, concrete_args)
    749         for module in self._autowrap_search:
    750             _autowrap_check(
    751                 patcher, module.__dict__, self._autowrap_function_ids
    752             )
    753         self.create_node(
    754             "output",
    755             "output",
--> 756             (self.create_arg(fn(*args)),),
    757             {},
    758             type_expr=fn.__annotations__.get("return", None),
    759         )
    761     self.submodule_paths = None
    762 finally:

File ~/Mokslas/AI/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vit_pytorch/vit.py:115, in ViT.forward(self, img)
    114 def forward(self, img):
--> 115     x = self.to_patch_embedding(img)
    116     b, n, _ = x.shape
    118     cls_tokens = repeat(self.cls_token, '1 1 d -> b 1 d', b = b)

File ~/Mokslas/AI/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/fx/_symbolic_trace.py:734, in Tracer.trace.<locals>.module_call_wrapper(mod, *args, **kwargs)
    727     return _orig_module_call(mod, *args, **kwargs)
    729 _autowrap_check(
    730     patcher,
    731     getattr(getattr(mod, "forward", mod), "__globals__", {}),
    732     self._autowrap_function_ids,
    733 )
--> 734 return self.call_module(mod, forward, args, kwargs)

File ~/Mokslas/AI/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/models/feature_extraction.py:83, in NodePathTracer.call_module(self, m, forward, args, kwargs)
...
--> 396     raise RuntimeError("'len' is not supported in symbolic tracing by default. If you want "
    397                        "this call to be recorded, please call torch.fx.wrap('len') at "
    398                        "module scope")

RuntimeError: 'len' is not supported in symbolic tracing by default. If you want this call to be recorded, please call torch.fx.wrap('len') at module scope
```

It doesn't matter which model I choose from that library or which layer or layers I choose to be outputed I always get the same error.

I have tried to add `torch.fx.wrap('len')` but the same problem persisted. I know I could try to solve it by using the hook methods, but is there a way to solve this problem so that I could still use the `create_feature_extractor()` functionality?

Comment: Where did you add `torch.fx.wrap('len')`?

Comment: I have tried adding it right after imports

Comment: And then you got "NameError: torch is not defined"?

Comment: No, I have also then imported torch